# "Require" seems doesn't work in systemd

Tags: linux, systemd

There are two services in my system : A and B.
Before start service A I want take some check automate. If check failed service A no need to start.
You may say that I can use  ExecStartPre or ExecStartPre. Yes, but it can not stop service A start.
So I want use "require" in systemd， create a new service B who config file like below:

```
[Unit]
Description=api
Documentation=https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes
Before=kubelet.service

[Service]

ExecStart=/bin/bash /root/check_init.sh 
Restart=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/root/check_init.sh like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
exit 1
```

service A config as below:

```
[Unit]
Description=Kubernetes Kubelet Server
Documentation=https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes
After=docker.service
After=api.service
Requires=api.service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/kubelet
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/kubernetes/config
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/kubernetes/kubelet
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet \
            $KUBE_LOGTOSTDERR \
            $KUBE_LOG_LEVEL \
            $KUBELET_API_SERVER \
            $KUBELET_ADDRESS \
            $KUBELET_PORT \
            $KUBELET_HOSTNAME \
            $KUBE_ALLOW_PRIV \
            $KUBELET_POD_INFRA_CONTAINER \
            $KUBELET_ARGS
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I thought service B start failed, so service A must failed too. However, service A started.
Is there any thing wrong for my config?
Thanks!

Comment: unclear why you don't want `ExecStartPre` instead, is it that you don't want the main service to be marked failed, but it's ok if this auxilary `api.service` is?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try to use `ExecStartPre` yesterday, systemd will restart service A again and again  until exec `ExecStartPre`  script success. The service A in `activating` status, it's worked for me. I also try `Type=oneshot` and `RemainAfterExit=yes ` for service B, its useful too. Service B run one time and if its failed service A will not start successful. The different for those two ways I think is: `ExecStartPre` will try to start service A again and again but the `Type=oneshot` and `RemainAfterExit=yes ` just only one time. Am I right?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense!  I hadn't considered that you had set  `Restart=`, sorry.

Comment: `kubelet` looks like it's a daemon, in which case it should not be `Type=oneshot`.

Comment: Yes, `kubelet` is a daemon. `Type=oneshot` for  `service B` not for kubelet(service A), `kubelet` need `restart=on-failure`. I think use `service B` not `ExecStartPre` is better for me. Because I actually want make some test before start the service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `Type=oneshot` in the first service - you're not actually waiting for the check to finish!

(Originally I suggested also using `RemainAfterExit=yes` in the first service.  But I *think* that was not necessary).